# Salary After Tax

Tags: java, arrays, math

I got one simple problem with my java assignment.I got my program running but I got a small issue. I want the correct calculation for the output which is the salary of employees minus the tax. I believe that I am not calculating it right.

Again. The problem is in the calculation itself

This is what I got in my calculation method

```
    public static void calculate (String[] lastName, double[] salaries, double[] schoolTaxRates, int count)
{
double total;

    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)

        salaries[x] *= schoolTaxRates[x];
        total = salaries[x] - schoolTaxRates[x];

This input file is: 
Jones     40000    .01
Smith     29000    .005
Abelson   60000    .0125
Johnson   30000    .01
Samuels   28000    .01
Blants    48000    .0075

The output after the calculation is ..
Jones $400.00 
Smith $145.00 
Abelson $750.00 
Johnson $300.00 
Samuels $280.00 
Blants $360.00
```

Could you guys help me with this?
Thnx

Comment: What's led you to believe it's not being calculated right?  Are *any* values in either array 0?

Comment: What's the current output and what do you expect it to be? What are the starting values of salaries and schoolTaxRates?

Comment: not entirely sure but it look like you are writing to same variable `total` i each iteration..so only last value wil survive

Comment: I edited my post to show what was in the input file and the output file. you can see the tax that should be cut from the salary in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines are not logical:

```
salaries[x] *= schoolTaxRates[x];
total = salaries[x] - schoolTaxRates[x];
```

For one index x, if the rate is 0.3. Salary is 10. Then what you are doing is change the salary to 3, then use 3 - 0.3 = 2.7.

I suggest you break down the salary calculation into one method with the following signature:

double getAfterTaxSalary(double salary, double rate);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, think object orientation.

Create an object:

- Object Employee with 3 fields

  - Name: string
  - Salary: double
  - Tax rate: double

Update your method signature:

```
public static double getTotalTax(List<Employee> employees)
```

Secondly think basic Math...

In your method, you do the for loop that iterates over the list and does:

```
total += employee.get(i).getSalary()*employee.get(i)*getTaxRate();
```